# Add odd and even to field--item with twig template

Tags: theming, 8

I'm trying to add "odd" and "even" to an image field (which contain multiple images) theming each item :

```
{% for item in items %}
  {% set zebra = cycle(['odd', 'even'], loop.index0) %}
{% endfor %}

{% for item in items %}
        <div{{ item.attributes.addClass('field--item', zebra) }} >{{ item.content }}</div>
      {% endfor %}
```

For an unknow reason the result of this code is :

```
<div class="field--item odd"></div>
<div class="field--item odd"></div>   
<div class="field--item odd"></div>    
<div class="field--item odd"></div>
```

What am I doing wrong ?

[EDIT]

Proper working code is :

```
{% for item in items %}
        {% set zebra = cycle(['odd', 'even'], loop.index0) %}
        <div{{ item.attributes.addClass('field--item', zebra) }} >{{ item.content }}</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: You have two separate `for` loops. Combine them into one.

Comment: Hi @NoSssweat, I've already tried before, putting the set variable into each for loops. Same result .... So code looks `{% for item in items %}
    {% set zebra = cycle(['odd', 'even'], loop.index0) %}
      <div{{ attributes.addClass(classes, 'field--item', zebra) }} >{{ item.content }}</div>
    {% endfor %}`. I also tried to put the cycle directly as a class attribute.

Comment: Ok, sorry I just needed to clear the cache. It works ... So dumb I am. But for my excuse I have to say that the behavior on D8 is not as on D7 where you can change your code as you wish without clearing cache all the time after your template is in base registry. So .... thanks a lot as usual.

Comment: This doesn't happen in D7, as in D7 by default caching comes turned off, while on D8 it's on. You can always disable D8 caching, [like this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rRsOxSuJ4OU), I would recommend you to do it during development.

Comment: Also, all browsers these days support odd/even coloring without having to add explicit classes: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp

Comment: @berdir Not in entity print. Entity print ship with dompdf or tcpdf which just allowed css2.1 and some css3.